# Refactoring of maven multi module project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

how can one change the package names and artifactId in a maven multi module project?
I need to change few module's artifact Ids and package names in a project with more than 25 modules.
Thank you

Comment: I've voted to remove the "uima" tag. If this is related to the UIMA framework, please specify why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press F2  over the package and change the name.
Eclipse will do the rest.

Comment: yes thank you for your reply. This works but I was kind of looking for over all solution for the whole project. I have way too many packages. But this works perfectly fine.